# Combine associative array with condition in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [14] => 2
    [28] => 1
)
```

what i need is an array with index value upto 31 where in ,except index 14 and 28 the value should be 0(zero) and the index 14 and 28 should have the value 2 and 1 respectively.

please help me  with this.

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's quite easy.

Comment: Didn't Clear that. Please Describe Clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this:-

```
<?php

$a = array_fill(0, 31, 0);
$a[14] = 2;
$a[28] = 1;
print_r($a);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/913931

Reference:- [PHP: array_fill - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways how to do it, for example:

```
<?php

$arr = array(14 => 2, 28 => 1);
$res = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    $res[$i] = isset($arr[$i]) ? $arr[$i] : 0;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Comment: @panther and Pooja Krishna Don't you think `array_fill()` is a much better idea rather than `for` loop?

Comment: Downvoters, please comment. This solution is the easiest for beginners, easiest for understanding. Array_fill is good alternative, not sure if for beginners.